# Basic Snowflake query slow with ORDER BY + LIMIT, does not prune partitions

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table in Snowflake containing time based event data, with different columns, and one `_timestamp` column of a Timestamp type. The `_timestsamp` column is also the clustering key of that table.

A very basic usecase on that table would be to see the latest 100 events:

`SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY _timestamp desc limit 100`

However, this query is very slow on a medium WH. (60+ seconds, on a few hundred milions of record).

Looking at the query profile, it looks like no partitions are pruned, meaning that snowflake is ordering the entire dataset before doing the limit. I imagined that the micro partitions are sorted, or at least contains metadata that will allow to only look at the partitions that have the latest timestamps.

In Postgres/MySQL, this query would be instant with an index on that timestamp column, since only the "end" of the index will be scanned.

Is there a way to help snowflake perform this query better? Is there something that needs to be done in ingestion time / query time?

Comment: Please POST TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE table; so we can see ALL the columns and indexes you have available, storage engine, primary key, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Without a `WHERE` clause, you won't prune anything and the `ORDER BY` will sort everything before running the `LIMIT`.  If you want this to run faster and the data is clustered by `_timestamp`, then be sure to use a `WHERE` clause with a reasonably small date range as well as the `LIMIT`.  For example, pick a date that is greater than yesterday (or last week or last month depending on larger your dataset is) so that Snowflake only has to fetch the most recent micropartitions and sort far less data.

Your other option is to not sort the data if the purpose of your limit is to just get a sample of the data, but that is likely a different use-case than what you are requesting.

Comment: Thanks, but since I have hundreds of milions of events per day, even adding a where clause for a day would result in the same number of partitions. It's a bit odd for me that this simple use case is not really working with snowflake, as i'm guessing it's very popular.

Comment: It would not be the same number of partitions if you used the where clause, that was my point to my post.  If the data is clustered on date, then partitions will only be chosen that have the date range you select on before ordering.

Comment: Sorry, I might not have been clear enough. This table is currently holding test data from only a day or two, not more than that. Meaning if I add a filter on the last day, it wouldnt filter that much, and would still have hundreds of millions of records to handle, and the query times will probably be around the same area.

Comment: My point was to filter on a timeframe that makes sense.  If the data is timestamp, could you choose the last 15 minutes or something like that?  The real point is...if you don't filter your data, it will not prune, it will sort everything, and then give you the LIMIT.

Answer (score 1):

[Improved Performance for SELECT Statements With LIMIT and ORDER BY Clauses](https://docs.snowflake.com/release-notes/2023-06#improved-performance-for-select-statements-with-limit-and-order-by-clauses-general-availability)

> **The improvement works by pruning micro-partitions that cannot affect the results of such “top K” queries. The additional pruning applies to queries where an integer-representable value (timestamp or integer, or variant explicitly cast to integer, but not an expression) is the first or only column specified in the ORDER BY clause.** If the query contains a JOIN clause, the ORDER BY column must be from the fact table (or probe side), typically the larger of the two tables.
>
> Queries on small tables generally do not benefit from this improvement. Queries that return fewer than the number of rows specified in the LIMIT clause, or that use aggregations, also do not benefit.
>
> Note that not all queries, not even all queries that meet these requirements, will benefit.

Answer (score 0):

LIMIT in order by would not help to speed up performance from perspective of working on reduced data-set, as ORDER BY is performed on the entire data before applying LIMIT.

For partition pruning, we also need to consider the selectivity of clustering key. _timestamp would most likely have all distinct values and there is no predicate to restrict which _timestamp value to choose as ORDER BY is on entire data-set and hence there will be no pruning as entire data-set will have to scanned for sorting (or getting sorted result-set).

Good information here - https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00007eNlhxSAC/why-doesnt-the-clustering-key-ensure-perfect-ordering-of-data

```
select * from SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCDS_SF100TCL.WEB_SALES order by WS_SOLD_TIME_SK limit 10;
```

[image]

I have quoted below from snowflake documentation (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-query-profile.html#profile-overview-operator-details).

SortWithLimit
Produces a part of the input sequence after sorting, typically a result of an ORDER BY ... LIMIT ... OFFSET ... construct in SQL. Attributes:
•   Sort keys — expression defining the sorting order.
•   Number of rows — number of rows produced.
•   Offset — position in the ordered sequence from which produced tuples are emitted.

Answer (score -1):

Is there a was you can show us the query profile of the SQL statement. Other thing could be check if the columns that you are in the WHERE clause of the  SQL are part of the Clustering key, if not try adding them and see if it helps.